# Common Lisp: all or any elements are true in a list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

In Python there are functions [`all`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) they return true if all or some elements of a list are true respectively. Are there equivalent functions in Common Lisp? If not, what is the most succinct and idiomatic way to write them?

Currently i have this:

```
(defun all (xs)
  (reduce (lambda (x y) (and x y)) xs :initial-value t))

(defun any (xs)
  (reduce (lambda (x y) (or x y)) xs :initial-value nil))
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Common Lisp, use [every](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm#every) (that's the equivalent of `all`) and [some](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm#some) (that's the equivalent of `any`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the LOOP macro with `ALWAYS` and `THEREIS` clauses like this:

```
CL-USER 1 > (loop for item in '(nil nil nil) always item)
NIL

CL-USER 2 > (loop for item in '(nil nil t) always item)
NIL

CL-USER 3 > (loop for item in '(t t t) always item)
T

CL-USER 4 > (loop for item in '(nil nil nil) thereis item)
NIL

CL-USER 5 > (loop for item in '(nil nil t) thereis item)
T

CL-USER 6 > (loop for item in '(t t t) thereis item)
T
```